# #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) update case

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, where-clause

I keep having this error when I try this :

```
update table1
set value1="apple"
where id IN (
select * table1_table2 where value2= "juice"
)
```

Comment: `select * table1_table2 where value2= "juice"` is missing a `from` clause, and likely contains more than one column, you need to specify which column you want to compare to `table.id`, e.g. `where id in (select table1Id from table1_table2 where value2= "juice")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not select multiple column inside in clause

```
update table1
set value1="apple"
where id IN (
select id from table1_table2 where value2= "juice"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out already, the problem is in the subquery which uses `SELECT *`, which is selecting two or more columns.  I would recommend using `EXISTS` logic here:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET value1 = 'apple'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1_table2 t12
              WHERE t12.some_id = t1.id AND t2.value = 'juice');
```

This answer assumes that the column from `table1_table2` which you want to compare against `table1#id` is called `some_id`.